# Getting The Sum From User Entered Data In DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to get the sum of data entered by the user in DataGridView cells.

Here is my code:

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender,      DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
         {
             if (e.RowIndex > -1)
             {
                 DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                 string monday = row.Cells[Column4.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string tuesday = row.Cells[Column5.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string wednesday = row.Cells[Column6.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string thursday = row.Cells[Column7.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string friday = row.Cells[Column8.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string saturday = row.Cells[Column9.Index].Value.ToString();
                 string sunday = row.Cells[Column10.Index].Value.ToString();

                 int result;

                 if (Int32.TryParse(monday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(tuesday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(wednesday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(thursday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(friday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(saturday, out result) && Int32.TryParse(sunday, out result))
                 {
                     row.Cells[Column11.Index].Value = monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday;
                 }
             }
         }
```

Every time I run this code I run into a NullReferenceException.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to debug line-by-line to figure out who is null referenced?

Comment: I thought that it might be from the cells in each column having no value in them yet. It happens when you enter a number in one cell and then try to go to another cell to enter another number.

Comment: you should try conditional access for example `row.Cells[Column4.Index]?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty`

Comment: The ?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty throws and error: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrements, await, new object expressions can be used as statements".

Comment: full line of code please?

Comment: sorry - string monday = row.Cells[Column4.Index]?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111868/discussion-between-elibyy-and-looneyviticus).